# How can i get information by manipulating two arrays in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two array one for present list and other for total lectures. i want a third array that will hold the percent of two

My first array (present days list)

```
$allpresentAttInfo = array(
        0 => array(
           'year' => '2013',
           'term' => 'T1',
           'presentDays' => '123' 
        ),
        1 => array(
           'year' => '2013',
           'term' => 'T2',
           'presentDays' => '112'
        )
    );
```

My Second array (Total days list)

```
$allAttInfo = array(
        0 => array(
           'year' => '2013',
           'term' => 'T1',
           'totalDays' => '200' 
        ),
        1 => array(
           'year' => '2013',
           'term' => 'T2',
           'totalDays' => '216'
        )
    );
```

My Resultant array should be like this

```
 $attInfo = array(
        0 => array(
            'year' => '2013',
            'term' => 'T1',
            'presentPercent' => '63.7 %'
        ),
        1 => array(
            'year' => '2013',
            'term' => 'T2',
            'presentPercent' => '42.7 %'
        )
    );
```

So by merging both the arrays i will have to find the present present in given year and term. How to achieve this on PHP side. Thanks in advance

Comment: [Since you haven't made an effort to solve the problem yourself, it seems that you're looking to hire a freelancer to do it for you](http://www.freelancer.com).

Comment: You should loop through the arrays using foreach($allpresentAttInfo as $index=>$key) some way and compare them, I'm not going to give you more information as you have not really coded something yourself

Comment: Thnaks guys .. please look my solution and suggest me performance optimization

Answer (score 0):

Well thanks guys .. I was in a hurry so searching for some short-cut copy paste way ... Well i coded it. but still give me some performance optimization if available.

My Solution is.

```
$attInfo = array();
    foreach ($allAttInfo as $allatt) {
        foreach ($allpresentAttInfo as $allpre) {
                if($allpre['year'] == $allatt['year'] && $allpre['term'] == $allatt['term']){
                   $presentPercent = round(($allpre['presentDays'] / $allatt['totalDay'])*100,2) . "%";
                   $newArray=array('year'=>$allpre['year'],'term'=>$allpre['term'],'presentPercent'=>$presentPercent);
                   array_push($attInfo, $newArray);
            }
        }
    }
```